# Excel - Comparing multiple cells to populate new value

Tags: excel

Hi all – I am a beginner in excel and apologize if I make this sound confusing.

I am having trouble with trying to create a formula where I compare two fields to another set of data containing two fields.

I have a table that provides logic for proper products:

```
Letter    Color     ProductName
A         Red       Product A
A         Blue      Product B
A         Orange    Product C
B         Red       Product D
```

I have another data sets that needs the product name populated:

```
Letter    Color    ProductName
A         Blue   
B         Red
```

I am having trouble comparing the combination of the first two fields in order to get the Product Name. Tried doing indexmatch but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your first table is called Table1 and the second is Table2.

What's VERY important about the Index/Match with multiple criteria is that you use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` in order to get the array formula.

If you don't have your tables in Table Format, simply replace those references with the correct ones. The important note with that is that they are all lined up identically (meaning the heights match and the starting and ending points match).

`{=index(Table1,Match(1,(Table1[Letter]=[@Letter])*(Table1[Color]*[@Color]),0),3)}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to work with VLOOKUP function (a function that will be useful in general on Excel, and I suggest you to learn it).

Basically you build keys on the columns used to match values of the initial column. Below a working example you can study.

A note: you have to check if the initial table has multiple values of the key: vlookup can return only the first it match!

[Working example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mY7u4TCw-EvQ5AlNWU1kKkR9eoijyvPw/view?usp=sharing)